# Unosquare.RaspberryIO: unregister from InterruptCallback

Tags: wiringpi, c#, interrupts

I'm developing an application on C# using Unosquare.RaspberryIO. My question related to interrupts and callbacks. According to the [documentation](https://github.com/unosquare/raspberryio#interrupts-and-callbacks), it's possible to register callbacks. For example:

```
pin.RegisterInterruptCallback(EdgeDetection.FallingEdge, ISRCallback);
```

But, how to unregister from them? Looks like the related method is not available in Unosquare.RaspberryIO. 
I have tried to reregister one more blank method on the same pin, like this:

```
pin.RegisterInterruptCallback(EdgeDetection.FallingEdge, () => { });
```

, but received an exception:

> "Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: An interrupt callback was already registered."

Any ideas how to solve this?

p.s. As an option, it can be possible to use if-else statement and bool variable. But, I don't like it.

Comment: What is Unosquare.RaspberryIO?

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, there is no way. Here is the code: https://github.com/unosquare/raspberryio/blob/master/src/Unosquare.RaspberryIO/Gpio/GpioPin.cs

The InterruptCallback cannot be changed once it is set (!).

You might wish to submit an issue to the library owners to address this lack.

As a workaround you might consider a hack where you pass in a callback that has its own callback pointer that you manage. Very ugly but...